# What is the safe way to append new elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I just want to ask for an appropriate way to append new elements in jQuery.
In the past, I tend to do string concatenation and then append to a div. However, sometimes my data contains special chars (like <>, %&, etc) and that obviously breaks my page.
After a bit of research, I found out jQuery .text() does offer automatically encoding. And I thought that it would be safer to create jQuery objects first, and then append. My code would looks something like this:

```
$.each(data.items, function(index, photo) {
            var $imageSpan = $("<span></span>").addClass("image");
            var $anchorTag = $("<a></a>").prop("href", photo.link);
            $("<img/>").prop("src", photo.media.m.replace("_m", "_o")).appendTo($anchorTag);
            $anchorTag.appendTo($imageSpan);

            $photoDiv.append($imageSpan);
        });
```

However, this page: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly points out that it is actually a horrible approach.
So, is there a way to be safe (text is all encoded) and achieve greatest performance?

Comment: I generally use `.replace(/</g,'&lt;')` when I'm feeling lazy. Simple and good enough.

Comment: OK, but how about other chars that need to encode?

Comment: `href` is an attribute, so requiring the `.attr()` function, not `.prop()`

Comment: Also, regarding that link you posted, I'd take that with a grain of salt if I were you. For all that he goes on about improving performance, [he seems averse to the simplicity (and speed) of vanilla JavaScript](http://jsperf.com/js-vs-jquery-again)

Comment: @Mark What other characters? `<` is the only unsafe character. `&` defines entities when in the right format, and personally I consider it a feature when users can enter `&eacute;` and get `é` out. If you disagree, a simple chained `.replace(/&/g,'&amp;')` fixes that.

Comment: jQuery’s [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) method can be used to set the text content of elements – and all necessary “escaping” is built-in, since it uses `document.createTextNode` internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, you're doing the right thing to make sure you don't have encoding issues. A great way to improve performance is to place the elements in an `Array` and only have the one call to `append` with that array. The main performance implications with multiple append calls is that the DOM may have to recompute the layout of the screen after each time, and that will slow everything down.

```
var photos = [];
$.each(data.items, function(index, photo) {
  var $imageSpan = $("<span></span>").addClass("image");
  var $anchorTag = $("<a></a>").prop("href", photo.link);
  $("<img/>").prop("src", photo.media.m.replace("_m", "_o")).appendTo($anchorTag);
  $anchorTag.appendTo($imageSpan);
  photos.push($imageSpan);
});
$photoDiv.append(photos);
```

I would also inline any HTML attributes which are *not* dynamic. For example, `.addClass("image")` is not very beneficial; would be faster to put that attribute inline, with `$('<span class="image"></span>')`.

Comment: How about the first two append ? Do you think they are performance hits?.
But thank you, your answer is short and precise, exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't think they would as much, since they are detached DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Mustache for this. I haven't done any benchmark tests, but performance should be good. The main thing, though, is that it makes it very easy to maintain and it handles html encoding the replaced values.

```js
var template = "{{#Images}}<span class='image'><a href='{{Href}}'><img src='{{Src}}'></a></span>{{/Images}}";
var model = {
  Images: [
    { Href: "http://www.example.com", Src: "myImage1.png" },
    { Href: "http://www.example.com", Src: "myImage2.png" },
  ]
};
$("#photos").html(Mustache.render(template, model));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.1.3/mustache.min.js"></script>
<div id="photos"></div>
```

Mustache has a very simple syntax: http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

There are of course other templating options, most of which offer more functionality than mustache (Handlebars, Hogan, etc).

Comment: Thank you. I think template will be a great option if I render complicated dynamic html

Comment: @Mark, Fair enough, but in my opinion it makes the code much easier to read even in your relatively simple example.  It also seems to be faster based on this: http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-mustache